# Curved arrow in xymatrix going over text

Tags: xy-pic

In some notes I took in a lecture, where I was using xymatrix to do the commutative diagrams, I found that a curved arrow beneath the diagram actually crossed over some text. (Ideally, the text should be lowered to accommodate the height of the "equation.") Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec}

\begin{document}

\[\xymatrix{
\Spec B^G \ar[r] \ar@/_2pc/[rr] & \Spec \widetilde{R} \ar[r] & \Spec R
\\ }\]

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this a bug?  In either case, how do I correct it, in a way simple enough to work when I am taking lecture notes in real time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether to classify this as a bug or a feature. :)

You can cure it by assigning an empty label to the curved arrow:

```
\[
\xymatrix{
  \Spec B^G \ar[r] \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{} & \Spec \widetilde{R} \ar[r] & \Spec R
}
\]
```